# Unable to access the route in .NET Core Web API

Tags: routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to access the route from the below code :

```
[ApiController]
[Route("{api/{controller}")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/{action}")]
    public IActionResult Employees()
    {
        return Ok("All Employees");
    }
}
```

When I tried to access with the url

```
https://localhost:44381/api/Home/Employees
```

I'm getting url not found error. Was my routing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you override the route in your api method
you have to follow the new route for that
in your case the link will be

```
https://localhost:44381/Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify specific routing on your Action, or specify your routing rules on the class, like this:

```
 [ApiController]
    [Route("api/{controller}/{action}")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        [HttpGet]
       
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Ok("All Test");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Employees()
        {
            return Ok("All Employees");
        }
    }
```

OR:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/{controller}")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {


        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Index}")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Ok("All Test");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("Employees")]
        public IActionResult Employees()
        {
            return Ok("All Employees");
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

For more usage, please refer to this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api